# String Linked List only printing last input

Tags: c, string, linked-list

I've been stuck on this for a while, can anyone help? 
my linked list code works fine for an integer but does not seem to work for strings, it only prints the last entry, any idea? 
Thanks

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include "node.h"
#include <string.h>

typedef struct node {
   char* val; 
   struct node* next;
 }node;

int main(){

// read text file
FILE * fp;
fp = fopen ("dict.txt", "r");

//  linked list

char i[10];

node* head = malloc(sizeof(node));
node* cursr=head;

while (fscanf(fp, "%s", i) !=EOF)
{
    fscanf(fp, "%s", i);
    //strcpy(cursr -> val,i);
    cursr -> val = i;
    printf("Read String1 |%s|\n", cursr->val );
    node* newnode = malloc(sizeof(node));
    cursr -> next = newnode;
    cursr = newnode;
}

cursr->next = NULL;
cursr=head;

while  (cursr -> next != NULL)
{
    printf("%s",cursr->val);
    cursr = cursr -> next;
}

}
```

Comment: Why did you comment `//strcpy(cursr -> val,i);` out? My guess is that line would fix your problem. Assuming, of course, that `cursr->val` has the required space allocated.

Comment: @Kninnug  he tried to assign in next line .He should use `strcpy` though.

Comment: Assuming `node`'s `val` member is `char*` (since you chose for whatever reason not to include the definition of `node`), consider this: I you do *not* understand that `cursr->val = i;` just stores the address of the `i[]` buffer in the node's `val` pointer member, and thus *every* node in your list, once built, has a `val` pointing to the same `i[]` buffer, you may need to review how pointers work in C.

Comment: so I commented //strcpy(cursr -> val,i); because this was giving me a core dumped. This is my node definition :       <br/> typedef struct node
{
    char* val;
    struct node* next;

}node;

Comment: Please don't post code here. It belongs in your question (along with all your other code). Regardless, lose the `cursr -> val = i;` assignment, put back your `strcpy`, and change your node `val` member to be `char val[10];` that is probably the quickest way to "fix" this (and I use that term liberally).

Comment: Thanks @WhozCraig . I made the fixes and it worked perfectly. I just have a couple of questions, so this is not just a temp fix. When I first used the code with ints  `cursr -> val = i;` seemed to be assigning the int value to each new node, why would that be? Since this is just a fix, what are the limitations of using such code and what would be the correct way to build a string linked list? Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this. it shall work.

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>
//#include "node.h"
#include <string.h>

typedef struct node {
   //char* val;
   char val[10];
   struct node* next;
 }node;

int main(){

// read text file
FILE * fp;
fp = fopen ("dict.txt", "r");

//  linked list

char i[10];
//int i;

node* head = malloc(sizeof(node));
node* cursr= head;

while (fscanf(fp, "%s", i) !=EOF)
{
    //fscanf(fp, "%s", i);
    strcpy(cursr -> val,i);
    //cursr -> val = i;
    printf("Read String1 |%s|\n", cursr->val );
    node* newnode = malloc(sizeof(node));
    cursr -> next = newnode;
    //cursr = newnode;
    cursr = newnode;
}

cursr->next = NULL;
cursr=head;

while  (cursr -> next != NULL)
{
    printf("%s",cursr->val);
    cursr = cursr -> next;
}

}
```